# Proof of Estimation Lemma (ML inequality) in Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, contour-integration, estimation

I'm having trouble seeing why the estimation lemma used in complex analysis is true. I didn't get much out the Wiki article or anywhere else, so I'm asking for an explanation or proof here. Specifically, it appears to me that using the greatest complex number magnitude is different than using a complex number itself, which has both a real and imaginary part. I can see that $|\int_Df(x)dx|\le\int_D|f(x)|dx$ where the domain of integration D is real.

Estimation Lemma: a maximum value for an integral is the maximum of $|f(z)|$ times arclength across the contour. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma

Comment: Here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma  is given a proof. What are your problems ?

Comment: I had a similar question to you. I wonder whether taking a look at this:  https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Modulus_of_Complex_Integral might help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\gamma\colon[a,b]\longrightarrow\mathbb C$ is a path and $M$ is an upper bound of $\lvert f\rvert$, then\begin{align}\left\lvert\int_\gamma f(x)\,\mathrm dz\right\rvert&=\left\lvert\int_a^bf\bigl(\gamma(t)\bigr)\gamma'(t)\,\mathrm dt\right\rvert\\&\leqslant\int_a^b\left\lvert f\bigl(\gamma(t)\bigr)\right\rvert\bigl\lvert\gamma'(t)\bigr\rvert\,\mathrm dt\\&\leqslant\int_a^bM\bigl\lvert\gamma'(t)\bigr\rvert\,\mathrm dt\\&=M\int_a^b\bigl\lvert\gamma'(t)\bigr\rvert\,\mathrm dt\\&=M\times(\text{length of }\gamma).\end{align}

Comment: I'm fine with all the steps you displayed, but why the | | bars in the starting equation? Don't those mean length of the complex number, like as in $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ for $x+iy$. How come it's valid to say that the value of an integral $I$ is the same as $|I|$?

Comment: They're **not** equal and I never claimed that they were.

Comment: Oh. So on the Wiki page in the example if a=3, isn't that interpreted as the maximum value of the integral is $\frac{3\pi}{64}$? I was using this for evaluating integrals with bounds $+\infty,-\infty$ along the real axis by picking a D shaped contour, and found that the imaginary part of the integral sunk to zero because this lemma said that that was it's upper bound.

Comment: There is no reference to the maximum value of the integral there. The idea is to find an upper bound of the **absolute value** of the integral.

Comment: Actually, I think I get it. Was the reason for the contour integral along the real axis being 0 because if the magnitude of a complex number is zero then the number itself is zero. Is that right?

Comment: Which contour integral along the real axis are you talking about?

Comment: $\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}$ and some functions in the inverse Laplace transform.